# How to sum a list in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
arr.rsplit(',', len(arr))

   print sum(arr)
```

If I input the string of "1,2,3,4", the first line splits it in a list of 1,2,3,4. But when I print the sum it does not work I get an error message.

Comment: Why are you specifically using `rsplit` over `split`, and passing the second argument when you don't need to limit the number of splits? Also, you have a list of strings, not integers, even if the strings contain textual representations of integers.

Answer (score 1):

In your case your splitting the string but the result is not assigned again to `arr` so your variable `arr` value is not getting changed it remains the string, so while you apply `sum(arr)` it is giving an error. But if you assign it to arr the type of split elements is `<class 'str'>` so convert it into `integer`

I trying to use `split` instead of `rsplit` Solution in Python 3 :

```
arr = "1,2,3,4"
arr = map(int,arr.split(','))
print(sum(arr))
```

Output : `10`

It will convert each element to integer and then take the sum. But if you try to print arr : `print(arr)` after the map method it gives output : `<map object at 0x7f90c081acc0>` So convert `arr` to `list` to access the elements So instead of `arr = map(int,arr.split(','))` give `arr = list(map(int,arr.split(',')))`

If you want to use `rsplit` then Solution (in python 3):

```
arr = "1,2,3,4"
arr = list(map(int,arr.rsplit(',', len(arr))))
print(sum(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split then convert the result to integers before you can sum.

```
arr_list = arr.split(',')
result = sum(int(i) for i in arr_list)
```

Comment: Exactly, or float depending if you want the numbers to be an integer or float.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sum your array is (you need to convert your array elements to be a floating point number, not a string):

```
i=0
for a in arr.split(','): i=i+float(a) #use int() if you want integers

print i
```

With your less efficient syntax this would simply be:

```
i=0
for a in arr.rsplit(',', len(arr)): i=i+float(a) #use int() if you want integers


print i
```

Hope this helps. Check out [this reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html) on types of variables